# Show html generated by using json2html at webpage [Django] [Python]?

Tags: python, json, django

Following is my code in view:

```
 RESULTS= {}
 for k in RESULTS_LIST[0].iterkeys():
   RESULTS[k] = list(results[k] for results in RESULTS_LIST)
 RESULTS.pop('_id',None)
 html_table =  json2html.convert(json=RESULTS)
 return render(request,'homepage.html',{'html_table':html_table})
```

here I am arranging a data fetched from Mongo Db in a JSON named as RESULTS and by using JSON2HTML package, it is successfully generated html table for data given in JSON. To embedd the html table code in a blank division at html page, I am doing:

```
<div>{{html_table}}</div>
```

But it failed to display the table on page. I have tried numerous ways to make it but didn't succeed. Please help me to resolve this issue. if any relevant example, you have done before , then please guide me in a right direction.

JS code is:

```
angular.module("homeapp",[])
.controller("homecontroller",['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){
    $scope.search= {
        'keyword': null,
        'option': null,
        'startDate':null,
        'lastDate': null
    };
    $scope.search_info=function(){
        var search_req = {
            url:'/home',
            method:'POST',
            data:$scope.search
        }
        $http(search_req) //in case I dont want any response back or
        $http(search_req).success(function(response){     
            window.alert(response)
         }) //in case I need to check response
    }

}]);
```

Comment: have you double checked if the `html_table` variable actually contains anything?

Comment: yes @danidee, I have checked through response sent back to Ajax call. Also i have printed the variable, in which I am storing this. Table code is generated successfully and data is inside it in a neat and clean form.

Comment: If you're using an Ajax call to render this, you should show that JS code.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman please check, if we can do it via JS as I am using Angular JS for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution to this problem in an easy way via using js, which is given below and it worked.

```
    $http(search_req).success(function(response){     
        angular.element(".search_results").append(response);
     })
```